# Game Entity Update Methods

Tags: c++, class, game-engine

I am writing a game in C++ with the SDL2 graphics library. I am using classes with inheritance to define entities in my game.

```
Entity
-> Player
-> BadGuy
-> Bullet
```

In this example, Player, BadGuy, and Bullet are all subclasses of Entity. I do this so that I can store a list of Entity in my game, and iterate through each entity to update and render them. Thus, each entity will have a unique `update()` to define their behavior.

The problem I run into is that in the update method, different entities cannot 'see' one another. If an instance of `Player` wants to check if an instance of `Bullet` is colliding with it, I would have to pass the list of all entities as an argument to `update()` for it to check. This doesn't seem so bad until you consider all the things an update method might need to reference. The game map, arbitrary game state information, and other things would all have to be passed as arguments for `update()` to use.

Is there an easy solution to this? Or a better but still similar programming pattern to use? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple messaging. When you update your game world, you check for collisions and message any objects that has collided with each other. This usually comes hand-in-hand with composition over inheritance. Read [this](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html).